# Fosuserbundle : Redirection to check email page after registration does'nt work on server

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I encounter a problem and I have no idea how to solve it.

I realized a symfony project in which there are user accounts (I used fosuserbundle). When a user registers, he is redirected to the "check-email" page.

It works fine from my local computer.

But on the server where the project is deposited, it brings me back on the registration form, the mail is sent but no check email page is displayed.

I have cleared the cache, all the files are up to date, so where can it come from?

If you have an idea, it would be great, thank you

Comment: Can you show your config.yml file?

Answer (score 1):

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }

# Put parameters here that don't need to change on each machine where the app is deployed
# http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/configuration.html#application-related-configuration
parameters:
    locale: fr

framework:
    #esi:             ~
    translator:      { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    secret:          "%secret%"
    router:
        resource: "%kernel.root_dir%/config/routing.yml"
        strict_requirements: ~
    form:            ~
    csrf_protection: ~
    validation:      { enable_annotations: true }
    #serializer:      { enable_annotations: true }
    templating:
        engines: ['twig']
    default_locale:  "%locale%"
    trusted_hosts:   ~
    trusted_proxies: ~
    session:
        # http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/framework.html#handler-id
        handler_id:  session.handler.native_file
        save_path:   "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/sessions/%kernel.environment%"
    fragments:       ~
    http_method_override: true
    assets: ~
    php_errors:
        log: true


# Twig Configuration
twig:
    debug:            "%kernel.debug%"
    strict_variables: "%kernel.debug%"
    form_themes:
        - 'bootstrap_3_horizontal_layout.html.twig'
        - 'VichUploaderBundle:Form:fields.html.twig'
    globals:
        nb_news_per_page: '%nb_news_per_page%'

# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        driver:   pdo_mysql
        host:     "%database_host%"
        port:     "%database_port%"
        dbname:   "%database_name%"
        user:     "%database_user%"
        password: "%database_password%"
        charset:  UTF8
        # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver:
        #   1. add the path in parameters.yml
        #     e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/../var/data/data.sqlite"
        #   2. Uncomment database_path in parameters.yml.dist
        #   3. Uncomment next line:
        #path:     "%database_path%"

    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
        naming_strategy: doctrine.orm.naming_strategy.underscore
        auto_mapping: true

# Swiftmailer Configuration
swiftmailer:
    transport: "%mailer_transport%"
    host:      "%mailer_host%"
    username:  "%mailer_user%"
    password:  "%mailer_password%"
    spool:     { type: memory }

knp_paginator:
    page_range: 6                     
    default_options:
        page_name: page              
        sort_field_name: sort         
        sort_direction_name: direction
        distinct: true                
    template:
        pagination: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:twitter_bootstrap_v3_pagination.html.twig    
        sortable: KnpPaginatorBundle:Pagination:sortable_link.html.twig

fos_user:
    db_driver: orm                      
    firewall_name: main                     
    user_class:    ACT\UserBundle\Entity\User
    registration:
        confirmation:
            enabled: true
            template: ACTUserBundle:Registration:email.txt.twig
    from_email:
        address: #mon adresse
        sender_name: admin
    service:
        user_manager: pugx_user_manager
        mailer: fos_user.mailer.twig_swift
    resetting:
        email:
            template: '@FOSUser/Resetting/email.txt.twig'


pugx_multi_user:
  users:
    user_candidat:
        entity:
            class: ACT\UserBundle\Entity\Candidat
        registration:
            form:
                type: ACT\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationCandidatFormType
                name: act_userbundle_candidat
            template: ACTUserBundle:Registration:user_candidat.form.html.twig
        profile:
            form:
                type: ACT\UserBundle\Form\ProfilCandidatFormType
            template: ACTUserBundle:Profile:user_candidat_p.form.html.twig
    user_referent:
        entity:
            class: ACT\UserBundle\Entity\Referent
        registration:
            form:
                type: ACT\UserBundle\Form\RegistrationReferentFormType
                name: act_userbundle_referent
            template: ACTUserBundle:Registration:user_referent.form.html.twig 
        profile:
           form:
                type: ACT\UserBundle\Form\ProfilReferentFormType
            template: ACTUserBundle:Profile:user_referent_p.form.html.twig


assetic:
  debug: '%kernel.debug%'
  use_controller: '%kernel.debug%'
  filters:
        cssrewrite: ~
        jsqueeze: ~
        scssphp:
            formatter: 'Leafo\ScssPhp\Formatter\Compressed'
```